# Redirect dynamic ID's to static url

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

I want to redirect my product pages with query string to my product pages without it. The site is in the WordPress and I want to do this with `.htaccess` file.

Example: `/abc/html?id=7` this id I have to redirect to `/abc` page in WordPress.

Comment: the both pages are from the same website?

Comment: yes they belong to the same website